# int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'function' in django messages

Tags: django, message

I am trying to use `messages framework` in my view, but its displaying the following error

**views.py**

```
def gcontacts(request):
    error = True
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.has_key('wow'):
            error = False
            messages.add_message(request, messages.success, 'Wow key exists !!!!')
        else:
            error = True
    return render_to_response('key_exists.html', {'error':error}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/Envs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 25, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/virtualenvironment/apps/myapp/views.py", line 33, in gcontacts
    messages.add_message(request, messages.success, 'Wow key exists !!!!')
  File "/home/Envs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/api.py", line 20, in add_message
    return request._messages.add(level, message, extra_tags)
  File "/home/Envs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/storage/base.py", line 153, in add
    level = int(level)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'function'
```

can anyone please let me know what i am doing wrong in the above code ?

Comment: it would be messages.SUCCESS

Comment: yeah sorry i identified :) but some what delay anyway thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

k done got the minute mistake ,

Actually `messages.success` should be `messages.SUCCESS`, and that worked !!!!